# Android app unable to download S3 Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: null)

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I am trying to read the metadata (version) of my s3 bucket and then decide if I need to download a sqlite.db file.

**Code**

```
private void downloadLatestSEZDBFile() {
        Object result;
        String finalDatabasePath = getFinalDatabasePath();
        s3client = new AmazonS3Client(
                new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider());
        try {
-->Exception here--> newVersion = Integer.valueOf((String) s3client.getObjectMetadata(
                    bucketName, sezDB).getRawMetadataValue(versionMetadata));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        }
        Log.d("myapp", "SEZDB version returned " + newVersion);
        File finalDatabase = new File(finalDatabasePath);
        if (newVersion == 1 || !finalDatabase.exists()) {
            copyVersion1FromAssets(finalDatabase);
            result = finalDatabase.getAbsolutePath();
        } else if (newVersion != God.getSEZDBVersion(context)) {
            GetObjectRequest objectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName,
                    sezDB);
            s3client.getObject(objectRequest, finalDatabase);
            result = finalDatabase.getAbsolutePath();
        } else
            result = null;

        if (result != null) {
            God.setSEZDBVersion(context, newVersion);
            sqliteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(
                    finalDatabasePath, null);
            God.initializeCityVariables(context);
        }
    }
```

I have copied `AwsCredentials.properties` to my `src` folder

```
secretKey=<mysecretkey>
accessKey=<myaccesskey>
```

**On AWS**

1. I have Dashboard->Identity & Access Management->Create IAM User (used the secretkey and accesskey in the AwsCredentials.properties file).
2. Added `S3ReadOnlyAccess` policy and `S3FullAccess` policy
3. On my s3 bucket, I have added `List` and `View Properties` for `Everyone` and `Authenticated_users`.
4. On my db file, I have added `Open/Download` and `View Properties` for `Everyone` and `Authenticated Users`.

**The Exception**

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: null; Request ID: DE30A17F3E9E3B1C), S3 Extended Request ID: fdl02MUW0qzC6WPzO52nUBCw4+LYxAPlUuPOWN2lJd+LRJLC/nUoM2AJip5yWxeG2fGhy7HIbLQ=
03-09 09:26:34.195: E/AndroidRuntime(31116):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(Unknown Source)
03-09 09:26:34.195: E/AndroidRuntime(31116):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(Unknown Source)
03-09 09:26:34.195: E/AndroidRuntime(31116):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(Unknown Source)
03-09 09:26:34.195: E/AndroidRuntime(31116):    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(Unknown Source)
03-09 09:26:34.195: E/AndroidRuntime(31116):    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(Unknown Source)
03-09 09:26:34.195: E/AndroidRuntime(31116):    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(Unknown Source)
03-09 09:26:34.195: E/AndroidRuntime(31116):    at com.myapp.support.ActiveSEZDB.downloadLatestSEZDBFile(ActiveSEZDB.java:262)
03-09 09:26:34.195: E/AndroidRuntime(31116):    at com.myapp.support.ActiveSEZDB.access$0(ActiveSEZDB.java:256)
03-09 09:26:34.195: E/AndroidRuntime(31116):    at com.myapp.support.ActiveSEZDB$1.run(ActiveSEZDB.java:43)
03-09 09:26:34.195: E/AndroidRuntime(31116):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
03-09 09:26:34.203: E/(1490): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
03-09 09:26:39.625: E/Launcher(1588): setWindowOpaque()
```

What am I missing here ?

**Edit**

1. I tried code from this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/3002109349624271), no change same exception as above.
2. I also tried moving the location of the AwsCredentials.properties to the libs folder. Here I got a different exception, hinting that the location of AwsCredentials.properties file should be in the src folder of the project and not libs folder.

> 03-09 19:19:57.109: E/AndroidRuntime(14502): com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from the /AwsCredentials.properties file on the classpath

3. I logged into AWS using IAM user, and I was able to view the metadata of the object.

Comment: @Praneet Sharma This issue is still open and not fixed..